# Como receber via serial informações em Hexadecimal no C#

Tags: c#

BEstou iniciando uma aplicação que recebe via seria os dados de uma interface em Hexadecimal, porém, quando os dados chegam, não são mostrados em um formato Hexa, me parece que estão sendo convertidos para ASCII . Por exemplo: os dados são enviados no formato pela interface 0B 01 10 2D 0D DC F2 e na aplicação são inseridos no listbox  -?? .

Existe alguma forma de filtrar isso e mostrar os dados no listbox conforme a interface enviou?

Segue abaixo a parte do código que é responsável pela recepção dos dados.

//************** DELAGATE DA THREAD *********************//
        public void serialCom_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(this.RecepcaoSerial));
        }

```
    //************** RECEPÇÃO DE DADOS *********************//
    public void RecepcaoSerial(object s, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread.Sleep(800);
        bufferRx += serialCom.ReadExisting();

        byte[] rawBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bufferRx);
        string str = BitConverter.ToString(rawBytes);
        str = BitConverter.ToString(rawBytes).Replace("-", " ");

        lstDadosEnviados.Items.Add(str);
        lstDadosEnviados.SelectedIndex = lstDadosEnviados.Items.Count - 1;
        lstDadosEnviados.SelectedIndex = -1;

        bufferRx = null;

    }
```

Comment: Por experiencia própria: Mexer com hexadecimal no C# é um pé no saco, sempre da um probleminha ou outro. Se possível, recomendo que converta para decimal ou use string.

Comment: Bom dia Francisco. Realmente está complicado,rsr.  Mas tem que ter alguma forma para isso...

Comment: Francisco, os dados saem da interface corretos "0B 01 10 2D 0D DC F2" mas quando ponho um acesspoint na linha da variável bufferRx, recebo assim, \v\u0001\u0010-\r??.

Comment: Hexadecicmal é bem tranquilo em C#, uma das mais simples de fazer. A questão é como você recebe a informação, são bytes, o que é normal, acho estranho ser diferente disto, ou se é um texto que no caso formam hexadecimais. Mostre pra gente como chega a informação. Se chega um texto `0B 01` não tem como mudar isto para bytes, é uma coisa horrível de fazer.

Comment: Bom dia bigown, os dados saem da interface em hexa mesmo, 0B 01 10 2D 0D DC F2, mas quando recebo esses dados na variável, bufferRx, os mesmos são apresentados assim, \v\u0001\u0010-\r??

Comment: Prezados, depois de quebrar um pouco a cabeça, consegui receber os dados da forma correta. Alterei o código que postei anteriormente, para o código com a solução.  Agradeço a todos pela ajuda.